# how to call JSNI function from Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

Here is caller button samples in html:

```
<input type='button' value='Call' onclick='Test()'>
```

And here are some functions I tried and which were not worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test() {
        com.tests.client.Test_GoogleWeb_JSNI::Callee()();
    }
</script>
```

But we are not able to call Callee().How we can achieve this?I mean how we can invoke JSNI function from javascript?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call GWT java function from Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619245/how-to-call-gwt-java-function-from-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very easy. You need to "export" your function written in GWT (or it can be another JSNI) function.

Here is the relevant documentation: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling

So in your case:

In your GWT code:

```
public static void Caller() /*-{ 
   ... 
}-*/

public static native void exportStaticMethod() /*-{
   $wnd.Callee =
      $entry(@com.tests.client.Test_GoogleWeb_JSNI::Callee());
}-*/;
```

Then you call `exportStaticMethod()` somewhere, even in your onModuleLoad. << YOU MUST DO THIS

Then you can call `Callee()` from your handwritten javascript code.

Your code for the button:

```
<input type='button' value='Call' onclick='$wnd.Callee();'>
```

Comment: Yes i tried but i am not able to invoke the function when we click on the button.

Comment: Have a look I updated my answer to show what the code for your button should be. Also if the function is not being called, I recommend you bring up your browser console (F12 in Chrome) and have a look for any exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

For chrome, the above solution works if I change onclick='$wnd.Callee() to onclick='window.Callee(). Chrome's  browser console tells us $wnd is not defined. $wnd is how to access the browser's window object in JSNI.

Sorry I couldn't just leave this as a comment (not enough points)

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling):

1. Make sure that `Test_GoogleWeb_JSNI.Callee()` is `static`.
2. Assign the Callee()-function to the window object.